# How to deploy a Windows VM with Terraform Azure CAF?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I want to deploy a Windows VM with **Azure Cloud Adoption Framework** (CAF) using Terraform. [In the example of configuration.tfvars](https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/blob/master/examples/compute/virtual_machine/101-single-windows-vm/configuration.tfvars), all the configuration is done.But I cannot find the correct terraform code to deploy this tfvars configuration.

The windows vm module is [here.](https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/blob/master/modules/compute/virtual_machine/vm_windows.tf)

So far, i have written the code below:

```
module "caf_virtual_machine" {
  source  = "aztfmod/caf/azurerm//modules/compute/virtual_machine"
  version = "5.0.0"
  # belows are the 7 required variables 

  base_tags = var.tags
  client_config = 
  global_settings = var.global_settings
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  settings = 
  vnets =  var.vnets  
}
```

So the `vnets, global_settings, resource_group_name` variables already exists in the configuration.tfvars. I have added `tags` and `location` variables to the configuration.tfvars.

But what should i enter to `settings` and `client_config` variables?

Comment: Do you just want to deploy a window VM reference that the file"terraform-azurerm-caf/modules/compute/virtual_machine/vm_windows.tf"?

Comment: @NancyXiong yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual machine is a private module. You should use it by calling the base CAF module.

The Readme of the terraform registry explains how to leverage the core CAF module - https://registry.terraform.io/modules/aztfmod/caf/azurerm/latest/submodules/virtual_machine

Source code of an example:
https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/tree/master/examples/compute/virtual_machine/211-vm-bastion-winrm-agents/registry

You have a library of configuration files examples showing how to deploy virtual machines

https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/tree/master/examples/compute/virtual_machine

```
   module "caf" {
    source  = "aztfmod/caf/azurerm"
    version = "5.0.0"
    
    global_settings    = var.global_settings
    tags               = var.tags
    resource_groups    = var.resource_groups
    storage_accounts   = var.storage_accounts
    keyvaults          = var.keyvaults
    managed_identities = var.managed_identities
    role_mapping       = var.role_mapping
    
    diagnostics = {
      # Get the diagnostics settings of services to create
      diagnostic_log_analytics    = var.diagnostic_log_analytics
      diagnostic_storage_accounts = var.diagnostic_storage_accounts
    }
    
    compute = {
      virtual_machines = var.virtual_machines
    }
    
    networking = {
      vnets                             = var.vnets
      network_security_group_definition = var.network_security_group_definition
      public_ip_addresses               = var.public_ip_addresses
    }
    
    security = {
      dynamic_keyvault_secrets = var.dynamic_keyvault_secrets
    }
  }
```

Note - it is recommended to leverage the VScode devcontainer provided in the source repository to execute the terraform deployment. The devcontainer includes the tooling required to deploy Azure solutions.

Comment: i am alredy using the configurations.tfvars in the example which is here:https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf/tree/master/examples/compute/virtual_machine/101-single-windows-vm

Comment: Ok. Let me update the public repo and will share with you the link here

Comment: @MoonHorse I have update the response. Let me know if that is helpful